# How to keep keyboard settings in the initial login screen? 17.04

Tags: keyboard, login, keyboard-layout, dvorak

I have set my keyboard to Dvorak system wide, but it isn't used for the login screen forcing me to use an on-screen keyboard.

I do have the keyboard settings menu where it should be, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I had just solved a similiar issue with my screen settings being the wrong way by copying my user settings into the light.dm folder (sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/lightdm/.config/), can I do something similiar, but with the keyboard settings instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Which Dvorak layout, more precisely? One way to let us know is to show us the output from the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Comment: Cool, thanks. [('xkb', 'us+dvorak'), ('xkb', 'ca+eng')]  I forgot to add it into my post (as it is likely unrelated), but Unity-Control-Center is not working, so I have no access to the GUI for system settings and a few other things.    What does "xkb" mean?

Comment: xkb is the keyboard configuration system used on most Linux distros. I posted an answer, which might be what you need.

Comment: Btw, if you use Unity, and unity-control-center isn't working, your system is severely broken. You may want to ask another question, if you want help to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and change the line starting with `XKBLAYOUT` to:

```
XKBLAYOUT="us"
```

and the line starting with `XKBVARIANT`to:

```
XKBVARIANT="dvorak"
```

(I assume that there is currently something else.)

After next reboot, the Dvorak layout will hopefully be effective on the login screen.

Comment: I edited the file to what you specified and rebooted, but it is still stuck in qwerty. Also; unity is working now, I don't know why.

Comment: @J.Tho: I see. Then I'm out of ideas, unfortunately. Maybe someone else can help.